# Generate or Obtain Google Maps Short "goo.gl/maps..." URL

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places

For a single location I can obtain the,

Long URL: https://www.google.com/maps/place/Kato+Restaurant/@34.0418978,-118.4633402,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x80c2bb684a20dd9d:0xa5a8ac9b5becd509!8m2!3d34.0419011!4d-118.4611438?hl=en-US

Web Provided Short URL: https://g.page/katorestaurant?share

Desired Short URL: https://goo.gl/maps/rVNsYdoULhhwKBY88 (Generated by Google Maps iOS app)

The API only provides the CID based URL: https://maps.google.com/?cid=11936980595607655689, which I'm not looking for.

Is there any other way to obtain the desired goo.gl/ short url?

Comment: I believe Google URL shortener was deprecated on favor of the https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links

Comment: It was but I can't use firebase to generate these